# hover effect and IE bug

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

[hover](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/projects1.html) seems to work fine in Firefox, safari..but not in IE. How to fix this?? Any insight?

here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3lVV.png)

Comment: which link is failing? effects look the same to me between FF and IE8

Comment: when you hover the mouse over the images on the right, it slides down beyond the boder.

Comment: Ah OK - it's not for me  - it's identical in IE8, FF3.6 and Chrome, it fails in IE7 and below, you said in a comment now removed that it was failing in 8

Comment: R u sure..didn't u see that the brown rectangle image sliding all the way down ??? I'm using IE8..how strange??

Comment: yep positive ;) I only saw the opaque rectangle once I checked in IE7.. have now answered, hopefully it fixes IE8 for U even though it's not broken for me eek!

Comment: I've attached the screenshot above..can u pls take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.case {position: relative;}
```

add to CSS